# ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to IBarDataSet

Tags: android, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have a problem using BarData. My code shows an error at :

```
BarData Data = new BarData(Date,depenses);
```

I only want to show the date under every bar.

My Code is..

```
public class statistique extends AppCompatActivity {

BarChart barChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistique);


    barChart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.stats_chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));


    BarDataSet depenses = new BarDataSet(entries, "depenses");

    ArrayList<String> Date = new ArrayList<>();
    Date.add("2/7/2016");
    Date.add("3/7/2016");
    Date.add("5/7/2016");
    Date.add("6/7/2016");
    Date.add("23/7/2016");
    Date.add("30/7/2016");


    BarData Data = new BarData(Date,depenses);
    barChart.setData(Data);

    barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    barChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
    barChart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDescription("Dépenses");
    depenses.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);



}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of the library are you using. The new v3.0 works slightly differently. If your using any v2 version the following will work. The error is misleading you need to cast your DataSets to IBarData sets, and it needs to be a list I believe.

This should work for you.

```
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add((IBarDataSet) depenses);
BarData Data = new BarData(Date, dataSets);
```

If you're using the new version 3 library, you need to set your XAxis differently. In that case you just need to pass

```
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add((IBarDataSet) depenses);
BarData Data = new BarData(dataSets);
```

You'll then need to setup your XAxis.

```
    IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return Date.get((int)value);
        }

        // we don't draw numbers, so no decimal digits needed
        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {  return 0; }
     };

XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:3.0.3'

List<BarEntry> grafdata = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create a method:

```
     public void barchardata(){      

    grafdata.add(new BarEntry( 0, Math.round(Float.valueOf(5.5f))));

    grafdata.add(new BarEntry( 1, Math.round(Float.valueOf(1.5f))));

    grafdata.add(new BarEntry( 2, Math.round(Float.valueOf(7.5f))));

    grafdata.add(new BarEntry( 3, Math.round(Float.valueOf(4.5f))));

    grafdata.add(new BarEntry( 4, Math.round(Float.valueOf(3.5f))));

    InitilizationBarChart();
}
```

```
 private void InitilizationBarChart() {

        BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(grafdata, "");

        barChartView.animateY(2000);

        BarData data = new BarData(bardataset);
        bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        bardataset.setValueTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        barChartView.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        barChartView.getXAxis().setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        barChartView.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChartView.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChartView.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChartView.getLegend().setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        barChartView.setData(data);


        final XAxis xAxis = barChartView.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(){
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return getXAxisValues().get((int) value);
            }
        });

        barChartView.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);


    }
```

Initialize name:

```
    private List<String> getXAxisValues() {
    ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
    UserNameList.clear();

    UserNameList.add("Rampal");

    UserNameList.add("sonu");

    UserNameList.add("Amber");

    UserNameList.add("Viresh");

    UserNameList.add("Pal");

    return UserNameList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
 barChart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.stats_chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));




    ArrayList<String> Date = new ArrayList<>();
    Date.add("2/7/2016");
    Date.add("3/7/2016");
    Date.add("5/7/2016");
    Date.add("6/7/2016");
    Date.add("23/7/2016");
    Date.add("30/7/2016");



    barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    barChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
    barChart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDescription("Dépenses");
    depenses.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
  ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(entries "your title");
     dataSets=new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(barDataSet)

 BarData Data = new BarData(Date,barDataSet1);
    barChart.setData(Data);
```

Comment: same problem BarData can only have one argument

Comment: post the logcat message

Comment: Error:(151, 24) error: constructor BarData in class BarData cannot be applied to given types;
required: IBarDataSet[]
found: ArrayList<String>,BarDataSet
reason: varargs mismatch; ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to IBarDataSet

Comment: try to change to change  dataSets.add(barDataSet); to dataSets.add(barDataSet1);